# Symfony Validation dependent on another property

Tags: symfony, symfony-validator

Trying to validate if one field is not empty (length > 0) then the length of the field being validated must be a certain length (2 characters). It seems like an "Assert\Expression" might work in this situation but I am having trouble trying to find the length of the properties. It seems like you cannot call php functions within the Expression. The [expression documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/syntax.html#working-with-functions) mentions functions but maybe I do not understand it... Do I need to register my own function that simply return a `strlen()`. If so how do you register your own functions? Can someone explain if there is a way to do this, or maybe there is a better way than using Expression that I am overlooking...

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="plate", type="string", length=10)
 */
private $plate;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="state", type="string", length=2)
 * @Assert\Expression(
 *     "strlen(this.getPlate()) == 0 or (strlen(this.getPlate()) > 0 and strlen(value) == 2)",
 *     message="Must be 2 characters"
 * )     
 */
private $state;
```

In the above case I get an error `The function "strlen" does not exist around position 1`

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Length.html

Comment: So you want to allow the field to either be empty, or if it's not empty it must have 2 chars length, Right?

Comment: Yes, but it's dependent upon the other property "PLATE"... So if PLATE is empty STATE can also be empty, but if PLATE has anything (Length > 0) then STATE must be length of 2

Comment: Sorry, my eyes tricked me. I amended my answer using a callback validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you will need to register your own function. Have a look at the docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/extending.html#registering-functions

There is an example on `lowercase`, `strlen` should be very similar.

**EDIT**:

You can also use a callback validator.

```
/**
 * @Assert\Callback()
 */
public function validateState(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    if (!empty($this->plate) && mb_strlen($this->state) !== 2) {
        $context->buildViolation('State must be 2 characters long')
            ->atPath('state')
            ->addViolation();
    }
}
```

But if you are planning to using this kind of validation in multiple places, you can write and register your own validator.

Comment: Worked except one modification... Had to have the function definition read: `public function validateState(ExecutionContext $context)`  (removed "Interface") not sure if thats right or not but it works